# Find out which polygons that are inside a surrounding polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a table with a lot of polygons, some polygons are inside a surrounding polygon. I would like to set the table attribute "inside" to "1" if it's a polygon that are surrounded by another polygon AND if the attribute "name" is the same.

If a polygon is a surrounding polygon or doesn't have any "inside" polygons I would like to set "inside" to "2".
The "inside" is set to "0" from the beginning.

The picture shows an example of this, I have highlighted a surrounding polygon and this polygon has the same "name" as the polygons inside.
The highlighted polygon and the polygons that has no inside polygons shall be set to 2 and the polygons inside the highlighted shall be set to 1 (all the surrounded polygons have the same name as the surrounding polygon, in this example).
How do I write an effective SQL command for this?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

```
UPDATE
  <table> AS t
SET
  inside = 2 - EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      <table> AS _t
    WHERE
      t."name" = _t."name"
    AND
      ST_ContainsProperly(_t.<geom>, t.<geom>)
  )::INT
;
```

where

- the `EXISTS` returns a `BOOL` (that can be cast (`::`) to `INT` in range `[0,1]`) indicating if any other *Polygon* contains the current one or not
- `ST_ContainsProperly` is used as a cheap means to make sure that for each *Polygon* the containment check fails on itself (because every geometry `ST_Contains` itself) - should even be cheaper than PK exclusion

---

The above `UPDATE` sets ***all*** *Polygons* to `inside = 2` ***except*** those that are within a *Polygon* of the same `"name"`, which are set to `inside = 1` instead.

I can think of more granular conditions - e.g. for *Polygons* that only partially overlap others with the same `"name"`, or with a different `"name"`, or that are completely isolated - that *could* make sense and where having an initial `0` is useful, but the above seems to be what you ask for.

If you *never* use the `0` - and the above behavior is correct - consider using `[0, 1]` as values instead, ***or use `BOOL` in the first place***.

Thus you could set `inside = 1` to those *Polygons* satisfying your *inside* condition by running:

```
UPDATE
  <table> AS t
SET
  inside = 1
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      <table> AS _t
    WHERE
      t."name" = _t."name"
    AND
      ST_ContainsProperly(_t.<geom>, t.<geom>)
  )
;
```

and all others would keep `inside = 0`; exact same result state, logically, but more in line with a `BOOL` condition.